# UK tax on dividends and sale of Shares for Non-residents

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom

**For a Non-UK Resident Individual (& Non-domiciled,) holding UK listed shares**
1.) Is there any UK income tax due on dividends paid form a UK listed company?

2.) Is there any UK capital gains tax due on the profit from sales of the shares?

**For a Non-UK Resident company, holding a UK listed shares**
3.) Is there any UK income tax due on dividends paid form a UK listed company?

4.) Is there any UK capital gains tax due on the profit from sales of the shares?

Cheers,

H